# How do I add an object to an array in php?

Tags: php, oop

I want to create an array within an object (handler) that holds a series of objects (subject) in PHP. The array is a property of the handler and I have a method to create new subjects.

```
class MyHandler (
  $TheList = array();
  $TempSubject = object; // class subject

  public function AddNewSubject($information) {
    $TempSubject = new subject($information);
    $This->TheList [] = $TempSubject;
  }
)
```

If I create a new subject as above, does the information persist object persist within `MyHandler` or is it lost after `AddNewSubject` ends? I am new to PHP so please comment on any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$TempSubject` within the object's method is only a temporary variable. If, however, you were to define your function like this:

```
public function AddNewSubject($information) {
  $this->TempSubject = new subject($information);
  $this->TheList [] = $this->TempSubject;
}
```

then the object's property (`$this->TempSubject`) would be updated each time but a copy of that object would be stored in `$this->TheList`.

Finally, if you were to define your function like this:

```
public function AddNewSubject($information) {
  $this->TempSubject = new subject($information);
  $this->TheList [] =& $this->TempSubject;
}
```

you would find that `$this->TheList` would contain a list of references to the same object, which would be overridden every time you call the function.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

It will persist, but you have a typo `$This` .. should be `$this`

Comment: Oh Boy! search and replace! :)

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question yes the object will persist in the class

```
class MyHandler (
     public $TheList = array();

     public function AddNewSubject($information) {
          $this->TheList[] = new subject($information);
     }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the array_push method, check it here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Why? `$array[] = "new value";` does the same thing

Comment: @xil3 `$array[]` is an alias of `array_push($array, ??)` so yes, it's the same thing. It's really all about author preferences.

Comment: @Truth I know what it is, but my point is that this answer didn't add any value to this question.